# Why is my washing machine standpipe overflowing even after snaking/jetting every way to Sunday?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, overflow

I have lived in my house for 3 years now with the same washing machine..in the past month my washing machine drain pipe has started to over flow. I do live in the country and drain my kitchen sink and washing machine into the field.

I started with a Drano/hot water. Nope

I have snaked the standpipe. The vent. Dug up the cleanout, and snaked towards the house and away from the house.

Used a water hose with a spray nozzle. In the standpipe, as well as in the clean out. 
THEN used a pressure washer with a jet tip...ran through the standpipe out to the field (40-45 feet).

Still to no avail.

Every time water was used, water was coming out of the end of the pipe in the field. Water was black and some debris came out...but not enough to clog a pipe. 
HELP!

I'm at my wits end and on a tight budget being a single (female) home owner. 
Could it be a collapsed pipe underground?
Sidenote: standpipe is correct height and girth.

Comment: Possibly relevant: Is that drain vented?

Comment: Yes it is vented. Even ran a snake down the vent.

Comment: You need to run a camera down, there is no other way to really see what is actually going on.  You can snake and jet all you want, but if there is a belly, collapse, offset, etc. you'll never know w/o the camera.

Comment: What kind of pipe is it? Iron? ABS/PVC? Orangeburg? Ceramic (I know, unlikely). If it's iron it could have rusted through and collapsed, ceramic could have cracked and be full of roots, Orangeburg could be collapsed and/or full of roots. Have you used a long enough snake to run from the cleanout clear through the other end of the pipe? I had something similar happening a few years ago and I had to rent a 75 foot electric snake, long enough to run from the cleanout in the basement all the way to the city sewer line. It definitely came back with roots stuck in the cutting blades.

Comment: Have you run a water test with the hose. This can help you locate where it might be backed up: How much water can be run into the stand pipe before it backs up? Some math and conversion app (cubic inches to gallons) (time the fill up of a 5 gal bucket to get flow rate.  I have used this method to eliminate possible blockage locations.

Comment: Once again, all pipes and vents have been snaked. Still will not drain.  I bought a 30' waterproof plumbers endoscope.....didn't see anything. Extended the stand pipe and changed the p-trap to a 90* rubber hose....and just flooded the was room again...about to pull my hair out.